# How to convert a colored image to something light and something white background in PS cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to convert a colored image to something light and something white background?

here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Desaturate the image (**Image** → **Adjustments** → ***Desaturate***)
2. Take out some of the black with levels (**Image** → **Adjustments** → ***Levels...***)
3. Make a new layer, fill it with white and then reduce the opacity until you have the right balance.

[image: example using method described]

Original image: [desktopography.net](http://desktopography.net/exhibition/2012/playground)

Comment: As always, there are a hundred ways of doing something in photoshop: desaturate image, increase lightness in hue/saturation (Image -> Adjustments -> Hue/saturation). Visible layers will have to be merged of course.